# How does java support instance variables of java enum constants?

Tags: java, enums

I know that in Java an `enum` constant is implicitly `static final` variable. But the `enum` class can have an instance variable say size. So each `enum` constant will have a copy of 'size'.
What is the equivalent Java code for this? I mean it "seems" the static `enum` constant is using a non-static instance variable which is not possible normally?

```
enum Members{
    A(1),B(2),C(3);  // I have 3 enum constants here

    private int size;
    Members (int size) {
        //System.out.println("Initializing var with size = "+size);
    }
}
```

Equivalent code I know so far:

```
public final class Member extends Enums<Members> {
    public static final Members A;
    // ...
    // What happened to size? How do A,B,C get a copy of size?
}
```

Edit : To restate my question-
I am interested in behind the scene implementation by compiler. I already know how to use enums. I am looking for what the compiler does? (so for example, if I simply write A, the compiler translates it to "public static final Member A". I want to know how compiler gives a copy of size to each A,B,C.

Comment: Don't confuse variables and references with objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I mean it "seems" the static enum constant is using a non-static instance variable which is not possible normally?

It is absolutely possible: each `static` variable in the `enum` is an object in its own right, complete with its instance variables. The instance is `static` in the `enum`, but it does not make the context of the instance itself a static context.

```
public final class Member extends java.lang.Enums<Members> {
    public static final Members A = new Member(1) {
        public String toString() { return "A:"+size; }
    };
    public static final Members B = new Member(2) {
        public String toString() { return "B:"+size; }
    };
    public static final Members C = new Member(3) {
        public String toString() { return "C:"+size; }
    };
    private final int size;
    protected Member(int size) { this.size = size; }
}
```

Comment: Why do you create a new class for each `Member` variable?

Comment: So what you are saying is that each enum constant A,B,C get a copy of size. So java takes my code and converts it to something like (create an instance var for A, for B and so on). That means compiler is doing some behind the scene thing. I was looking for that behind the scene thing .

Comment: What I meant by "normally" was that in non-enum classes a static variable can't access non static variables.

Comment: @rents "That means compiler is doing some behind the scene thing. I was looking for that behind the scene thing ." Absolutely, compiler does lots of things behind your back, letting you use convenient syntax. There's a lot more going on than what you write in generics, in nested classes, with autoboxing, and with `enum`s.

Comment: @rents "in non-enum classes a static variable can't access non static variables." You probably meant "static methods cannot access non-static variables", right? That's the trick: it's variables `A`, `B`, and `C` that are static, but each of these variables points to a first-class object, which has instance variables, can have instance methods, and so on.

Comment: @msrd0 So that you could override methods individually. I expanded the example to show overriding `toString()`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks. I understand that not all what compiler does can be as easily expressed as was the case with my example (A => public static final Member A) and so is the case with the instance var here. And Yes, I meant static methods only.

Answer (score 2):

> I mean it "seems" the static enum constant is using a non-static instance variable which is not possible normally?
>
> What I meant by "normally" was that in non-enum classes a static variable can't access non static variables

It's still true: a static variable can't access non-static variables.
In your example code, you don't do this:
there is no static variable accessing non-static variables.

The constructor `Members(int size)` is not in a static context (a constructor never is).
A, B and C are all instances of the enum type `Members`,
and when these instances are created,
the constructor is called with the `size` parameter.
Once constructed, these objects will be treated as static constant values.

Perhaps another example can help:

```
class Person {
    private final String name;
    Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
class EmployeeDatabase {
    private static final Person CEO = new Person("Jack");
}
```

Here `EmployeeDatabase.CEO` is a static constant object with a non-static field `name`.
This is just like `Members.A`, a static constant object with a non-static field `size`.

> I want to know how compiler gives a copy of size to each A,B,C.

Exactly the same way as it passes constructor parameters to any object.

You can read all about enums in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Comment: This will not compile, `size` mustn't be final

Comment: Sure it does. Not only it can be final, it *should be* final. A mutable enum would be very weak design.

Comment: Won't javac show an error if you have a `final` variable that wasn't initialized? And when a `final` variable is initialized in ctor?

Comment: @msrd0 He is initializing it in the constructor. Variables declared with `final` can only be initialized directly with the declaration (`private final int blub = 0;`) or in a constructor.

Comment: I am not looking for this. I am more interested in behind the scene implementation by compiler. I already know how to used enums. I am looking for what compiler does? (so for example, if I simply write A, the compiler translates it to "public static final Member A". I want to know how compiler gives a copy of size to each A,B,C.